# Create a SharePoint Survey from an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to import information into a survey from an external datasource? I have a user who has a spreadsheet full of measures (Over 300 of them) who would like to create a few surveys in SharePoint so that he could ask our users to rate some software based on these measures.

Manual data entry of all 300+ measures directly into a survey would take a LOT of time. Is there an easy way to get these measures into a survey?

Thanks to Adam for his answer below. As an admin, some pointers as to how to use these objects from Power Shell or Iron Python would help as well.

Comment: Give this a shout over on StackOverflow.com also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never done it myself, but perhaps you could combine [this code which programmatically creates the basics of a survey](http://blog.walisystemsinc.com/2006/11/creating-survey-in-moss-2007_03.html) with [this code which adds the questions](https://web.archive.org/web/20131011013001/http://msmvps.com:80/blogs/sundar_narasiman/archive/2008/08/14/programmatically-create-sharepoint-survey-questions.aspx). It shouldn't be too hard to do some sort of mail merge to convert your user's spreadsheet into code which will create the questions.

Comment: Links are dead as of January 2018.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this tool would be useful to you. It is called SharePoint Survey Loader. It allows you to input possible answers separated by semicolons so I'm thinking save as custom CSV file from your spreadsheet.

http://sharepointsurveyimportloader.cyberpine.com/